# PhoneGap ondeviceready not firing after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, android, events, cordova

So I am currently debugging my PhoneGap app using Weinre and I keep getting the errors below...

deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.

Channel not fired: onPluginsReady

Channel not fired: onCordovaReady

Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady

I am using the barcodescanner plugin and compiling with the remote service provided by the PhoneGap website. Also using PhoneGap 3.2 on android 2.3.

```
this.initialize = function(){
    this.bindEvents();
};

this.bindEvents = function(){
    console.log('binding events...');
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
};
this.onDeviceReady(){
...
};
```

The initialize function is called in the body onload event.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);`?

Answer (score 0):

Does a brand new phonegap project work with phonegap 3.2.0 for you?
We experienced the same issue, and it turned out that even the stock sample webapp got the same errors when running with phonegap 3.2.0:

```
[Log] deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. (phonegap.js, line 1078)
[Log] Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady (phonegap.js, line 1071)
```

Not sure why. Downgrading to 3.0.0 is a workaround:

```
npm install -g phonegap@3.0.0-0.14.4 cordova@3.0.10
```

Then create a new phonegap project and see if it works using 3.0.0. Does so for us.

Answer (score 0):

In my case a problem was in cordova.js and plugins. I got it from iOS version, not from Android and received an error.

Answer (score -3):

Use the below method.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("on device ready");
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```